# Missing content in newsfeed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

If I compare the content on https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=... and my actual facebook news feed, they are not the same as each other ie one has content that the other doesn't have and vica versa...? Is there a way to get "all" of it in the news feed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

It says "News feed (this is an outdated view, does not reflect the News Feed on facebook.com): https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=..."

As far as I know, there is no way to get the exact news feed with Facebook's current APIs.